# Ternary operator in C

Tags: c

Why this program is giving unexpected numbers(ex: `2040866504`, `-786655336`)?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main()
{
     int test = 0;
     float fvalue = 3.111f;
     printf("%d", test? fvalue : 0);

     return 0;
}
```

Why it is printing unexpected numbers instead of `0`? should it supposed to do implicit typecast? This program is for learning purpose nothing serious.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "random"? You're trying to print a floating point number as an integer, but that number should be `0` which has the same bit representation in both types.

Comment: Random, or just incorrect?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about who knows what.


Comment: I think the expectation was that, because `test` is boolean false, the `printf` should be attempting to print the `0`, which is an integer. Instead it prints a random number like `1809054712` for me on a given run.

Comment: Pick either integer or float and stick with. You can't split the difference.

Comment: @Prashant, the `0` will be promoted to floating point by the ternary operator. As I said it shouldn't matter because a floating point `0.0` is still a bunch of 0 bits.

Comment: My test gives the result I would expect, not at all random: http://ideone.com/2MFlz1

Comment: @MarkRansom That's how Undefined Behavior is. Sometimes it does what you expect, sometimes it does what I expect. Sometimes it does what nobody expects.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Your test gives the result you (wrongly) expect because you're running it on an implementation where argument-passing for floating point and integer arguments uses the same storage and where the representation of `0.0` as a `double` is all-zero-bits.

Comment: Question: which compiler and OS did you use?

Comment: @Tonmoy just FYI since it looks like you're learning, computer terms like "random" have very specific meanings and it's poor form to use them incorrectly. You have unexpected numbers, not random ones.

Comment: @Adam if you get different results every time you run, that would qualify as "random" to me.

Comment: @R.. so this might be explained by register-based parameter passing where integers and floating point parameters use different registers.

Comment: @MarkRansom: That's one of infinitely many possible implementation choices that would be valid and consistent with the behavior OP is observing when invoking UB here. But it's not the explanation. The explanation is simply that the behavior is undefined. Any form of "expectation" that it should give a particular result, despite being undefined, is wrong.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, my observation is that even undefined behavior generally has a rational explanation. I've yet to see demons flying out of anyone's nostrils.

Comment: Given that the OP may only be learning C at an elementary level though, the type promotion in the ternary operator may have surprised him, and simply stating that it is UB is sufficient.

Comment: @MarkRansom How long have you been programming? I've seen a dog get pregnant and a dishwasher break. Nostril demons, however, I too believe to be apocryphal.

Comment: However, the compiler should have warned you about the ternary operator having been given two different types at least with warnings on (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`).

Comment: I have intentionally given two different types for experimenting with ternary operators. So, i ignored those errors.

Comment: @alk: Why would you expect a warning for that? I've never heard of implicit conversions which are promotions producing warnings.

Comment: @R..: *sigh* promotion stroke again; you are right, thanks for pointing this out. I was reflecting on the warning which would have been given by for example `<bool-value> ?(T1*)1 :(T2*)1`

Comment: @alk: In that case, it would be a constraint violation (unless either `T1` or `T2` is `void`) and the compiler is required to issue a diagnostic. A good compiler should not even accept it but treat it as fatal.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Most likely, your platform passes floating point values in a floating point register and integer values in a different register (or on the stack). You told `printf` to look for an integer, so it's looking in the register integers are passed in (or on the stack). But you passed it a `float`, so the zero was placed in the floating point register that `printf` never looked at.

The ternary operator follows language rules to decide the type of its result. It can't sometimes be an integer and sometimes be a float. Those could be different sizes, stored in different places, and so on, which would make it impossible to generate sane code to handle both possible result types.

This is a guess. Perhaps something completely different is happening. Undefined behavior is undefined for a reason. These kinds of things can be impossible to predict and very difficult to understand without lots of experience and knowledge of platform and compiler details. Never let someone convince you that UB is okay or safe because it seems to work on their system.

Comment: The only thing missing from this answer is why the parameter was floating point in the first place.

Comment: I added some more information about that in the middle paragraph.

Comment: @Tonmoy What *is* your platform?  Compiling 32- and 64-bit, optimized on and off, on VS2012 I get zero for for all attempts (Yes, I understand UB, just wondering what the platform is).

Comment: im compiling in gcc..and my system is 64bit

Comment: It's kind of puzzling that if you use scanf to parse the test variable from user input it works, even when the same printf line is used...

Comment: @vinaut: It's not necessarily very puzzling. Having called another function previously (whichever function that is, really) may put the registers and/or stack in a different state. Normally, that's not among the things that `printf` should be looking at, if undefined behavior weren't invoked. It doesn't actually "work" -- it just does something different undefined that has the same appearance as "working".

Comment: @Dolda2000:  I would argue that in this case "works" as expected (in the sense that at least the ternary operator is processed correctly, even if the code is flawed). But I agree, the additional code before the printf probably perform some sort of initialization/cleaning that in the original case was absent.

Answer (score 11):

Because you are using `%d` for printing a `float` value. Use `%f`. Using `%d` to print a `float` value invokes **undefined behavior**.

---

EDIT:
Regarding OP's comments;

> Why it is printing random numbers instead of 0?

When you compile this code, compiler should give you a warning:

```
[Warning] format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat]
```

This warning is self explanatory that this line of code is invoking an undefined behavior. This is because, the conversion specification `%d` specifies that `printf` is to convert an `int` value from binary to a string of decimal digits, while `%f` does the same for a `float` value. On passing the `fvalue` compiler know that it is of `float` type but on the other hand it sees that `printf` expects an argument of type `int`. In such cases, *sometimes it does what you expect, sometimes it does what I expect. Sometimes it does what nobody expects* (Nice Comment by [David Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063517/ternary-operator-in-c/19063532#comment28176390_19063517)).
See the test cases [1](http://ideone.com/Ig5uub) and [2](http://ideone.com/woe4XU). It is working fine with `%f`.

> should it supposed to do implicit typecast?

No.

Comment: True, but I don't think it matters with the specific code shown here.

Comment: Why it is printing random numbers instead of 0? should it supposed to do implicit typecast?

Comment: @MarkRansom; Why? See the test cases [1](http://ideone.com/Ig5uub) and [2](http://ideone.com/woe4XU).

Comment: @MarkRansom: It most definitely does matter.

Comment: @Tonmoy It's not like the C language looks at your `%d` and says, "Oh, I need an integer". It's your responsibility to match the parameter types to the specifier. (Some compilers will give you a warning if you mess it up.)

Comment: @R.. then explain how. As I said the bit patterns for `0` and `0.0f` should be identical, unless this is a platform where `int` is 64 bits.

Comment: @Tonmoy "implicit typecast" is an oxymoron, typecasts are explicit by definition. Perhaps you are talking about "implicit conversion". But even that isn't done (apart from a `float` being promoted to a `double` when passed to a variadic function). `printf()` is not magic.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Your idea of "should" is wrong. Even if the representations are the same, there is no reason this should work as you expect. Also the argument is `0.0` (a `double`) not `0.0f` (a `float`) because of default promotions.

Comment: exp1?exp2:exp3...in C does data type of exp3 depends on data type of exp2?

Comment: @Tonmoy See [this page](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cc-ternary-operator-some-interesting-observations/) discussing this exact issue (well, almost).

Comment: @Tonmoy;No. It does not.

Comment: @Tonmoy: The type of `exp3` does not depend on the type of `exp2`, but the type of the expression as a whole depends on them both. Similar to how `3` is type `int`, `2.0` is type `double`, but the value of the expression `(3 + 2.0)` as a whole is type `double`. Ternary operators would lead to chaos if the type of the expression changed depending on whether the condition was true or false.

Answer (score 8):

Although the existing upvoted answers are correct, I think they are far too technical and ignore the logic a beginner programmer might have:

Let's look at the statement causing confusion in some heads:

```
printf("%d", test? fvalue : 0);
        ^    ^     ^        ^
        |    |     |        |
        |    |     |        - the value we expect, an integral constant, hooray!
        |    |     - a float value, this won't be printed as the test doesn't evaluate to true 
        |    - an integral value of 0, will evaluate to false
        - We will print an integer!
```

What the compiler sees is a bit different. He agrees on the value of `test` meaning `false`. He agrees on `fvalue` beeing a `float` and `0` an integer. However, he learned that the different possible outcomes of the ternary operator must be of same type! `int` and `float` aren't. In this case, "`float` wins", `0` becomes `0.0f`!

Now `printf` isn't type safe. This means you can falsely say "print me an integer" and pass an float without the compiler noticing. Exactly that happened. No matter what the value of `test` is, the compiler deduced that the result will be of type `float`. Hence, your code is equivalent to:

```
float x = 0.0f;
printf("%d", x);
```

At this point, you experience undefined behaviour. `float` simply isn't something `integral` what is expected by `%d`.

The observed behaviour is dependent on the compiler and machine you're using. You may see dancing elephants, although most terminals don't support that afaik.

Answer (score 1):

When we have the expression `E1 ? E2 : E3`, there are four types involved. Expressions `E1`, `E2` and `E3` each have a type (and the types of `E2` and `E3` can be different). Furthermore, the whole expression `E1 ? E2 : E3` has a type.

If `E2` and `E3` have the same type, then this is easy: the overall expression has that type. We can express this in a meta-notation like this:

```
(T1 ? T2 : T2) -> T2 
"The type of a ternary expression whose alterantives are both of the same type T2
 is just T2."
```

If they don't have the same type, things get somewhat interesting, and the situation is quite similar to `E2` and `E3` being involved together in an arithmetic operation. For instance if you add together an `int` and `float`, the `int` operand is converted to `float`. That is what is happening in your program. The type situation is:

```
(int ? float : int) -> float
```

the test fails, and so the `int` value `0` is converted to the `float` value `0.0`.

This `float` value is not compatible with the `%d` conversion specifier of `printf`, which requires an `int`.

More precisely, the `float` value undergoes one more. When a `float` is passed as one of the trailing arguments to a variadic function, it is converted to `double`.

So in fact the `double` value 0.0 is being passed to `printf` where it expects `int`.

In any case, it is undefined behavior: it is nonportable code for which the ISO standard definition of the C language doesn't offer a meaning.

From here on, we can apply platform-specific reasoning why we don't just see `0`. Suppose `int` is a 32 bit, four byte type, and `double` is the common 64 bit, 8 byte, IEE754 representation, and that an all-bits-zero is used for `0.0`. **So then, why isn't a 32 bit portion of this all-bits-zero treated by `printf` as the `int` value `0`?**

Quite possibly, the 64 bit `double` argument value forces 8 byte alignment when it is put onto the stack, possibly moving the stack pointer by four bytes. And then `printf` pulls out garbage from those four bytes, rather than zero bits from the `double` value.